# How to set width for MudBlazor form?

Tags: c#, blazor, webassembly, mudblazor

I'm trying to create a simple login form with MudBlazor but for some reason it shows up extremely narrow and I can't find any `Width` property on components. How do I set the width?

```
<EditForm Model="@loginModel" OnValidSubmit="OnValidLoginSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <MudGrid>
        <MudItem xs="12" sm="7">
            <MudPaper>
                <MudCardContent>
                    <MudTextField Label="Username or email"
                    @bind-Value="loginModel.UsernameOrEmail"
                    For="@(() => loginModel.UsernameOrEmail)" />
                    <MudTextField Label="Password" HelperText="Type your password" Class="mt-3"
                    @bind-Value="loginModel.Password"
                    For="@(() => loginModel.Password)" InputType="InputType.Password" />
                </MudCardContent>
                <MudCardActions>
                    <MudButton ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit" Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" Class="ml-auto">Login</MudButton>
                </MudCardActions>
            </MudPaper>
        </MudItem>
    </MudGrid>
</EditForm>
```

Ideally, I'd like to set some specific width when the screen is wide enough and also set a minimal width down to which components could shrink if the screen is shrinked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of these below, if you mean the card width.

```
<MudCard Style="width:200px">

//or 

<MudPaper Width="300px">
```

For other components, use the `Style` property if it doesn't have a `Width` property.